# Delete cache from server using php code

Tags: php, caching

I am using wp framework and i am getting `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` when i run the site, This may be because of server cache .Is it possible to clear cache from server using php code, If yes then how can we delete cache.

Comment: What cache you are talking about?

Comment: After edited file i am getting error that's why i undo all changes but getting same error. So i am not getting which cache should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking about php cache, it can be flushed with restarting php. If it is application cache - you should delete cache files.